# iOS Fire Gesture Recognizer when View Held Over Another View

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I guess the question says it all, but what I'm trying to do is to fire a long-press gesture recognizer when a UIView is dragged and held over another UIView.  If the long press is directly on the view beneath, it works as it should.  But I also need for the recognizer to fire when a view is held over the target view, and I'm getting nowhere on this.

Any suggestions?

TIA

Comment: How is the 'target view' not 'the view beneath'? You mean you can drag any view over any other and need to mediate between the multiple recognisers on each view?

Comment: Create a demo project on DropBox and offer a small bounty for the solution in code.